# GtkStatusIcon does not display custom icon

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I'm using gtkmm on Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm having some trouble getting my custom icon displaying on the system tray.

I am using `GtkStatusIcon` and doing a set from file to a custom icon called icon.png. I do not see errors when I add debug statements however, I do not see the icon in the system tray either. Is there another step to add to `set_from_file()` in Tray.cpp?

Here's my code.

**Tray.h**

```cpp
#ifndef GTKMM_TRAY_H
#define GTKMM_TRAY_H

#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

class Tray : public Gtk::StatusIcon
{
    public:
        Tray();
        ~Tray();

    private:
        virtual void on_statusicon_popup(guint button, guint activate_time);
        virtual void on_statusicon_activated();
};
```

**Tray.cpp**

```cpp
#include "Tray.h"

Tray::Tray()
{
    set_from_file("/home/user/icons/icon.png");

    signal_activate().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &Tray::on_statusicon_activated));
    signal_popup_menu().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &Tray::on_statusicon_popup));

    set_visible(true);
}

Tray::~Tray() {}

void Tray::on_statusicon_popup(guint button, guint activate_time)
{
    printf("popup!");
}

void Tray::on_statusicon_activated()
{
    printf("active!");
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <gtkmm/main.h>
#include "Tray.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);
    
    Tray tray;
    
    Gtk::Main::run();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Works fine here. In your question you say your icon file is `icon.jpg` but in the code it says `icon.png`. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. png is correct. I updated it to absolute path to be sure.

Comment: My is_embedded is returning false.

Comment: Kinda boggles the mind that a function like [set_from_file](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1StatusIcon.html#adf0aeb58ab868156646d0a600d3cbc61) has a void return value.  Pass garbage, pretend it will work anyway.  That it got deprecated 6 years ago is not surprising.

Comment: What is `is_embedded`?

Comment: 'is_embedded' is a Gtk::StatusIcon boolean function that returns whether the status icon is embedded in a notification area.